# Find network path of shared drive on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, networking, mac, airport, icloud

I have two Time Capsules, that are currently located on a different network (one is directly connected to the WAN, the other is behind the first one), that are mounted on my MacBook Pro using Back to my Mac. I want to see the network path of these drives so I can also mount them on my Windows machine as well. How do I do that?

Comment: see http://techsupport.foreverwarm.com/time-capsule-windows#harddisk Way too much to precis here

Comment: @Tetsujin this is not what I'm looking for. My time capsule is on a totally different network.

Answer (score 1):

Back to my Mac uses a VPN-style tunnel, so this is not how you want to do this.
What you ought to do is: buy a NAS such as a [Synology](http://www.synology.com) or [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com), then copy all the data from the Time Capsule to the Synology. Then you have more flexibility because the Synology can be mounted from the Mac or Windows.
It has its own VPN if you prefer to use that.